# Remote X Server uses different OpenGL renderer when started via `ssh -X` vs remote-side `/usr/bin/X` - why?

Tags: opengl, ssh, nvidia, xorg, xserver

We are trying to run `glxinfo` and `glxgears` using an Nvidia GPU and driver on a remote Ubuntu server, while forwarding the display to a local Mac through XQuartz.

We have noticed that OpenGL uses a different renderer (dedicated GPU vs onboard graphics), depending on whether the remote X server is started via `ssh -X` from the Mac or via `sudo /usr/bin/X` inside the remote [per this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-unity-on-amazon-cloud-or-without-monitor-3c10ce022639).

**Case 1**

If we execute `sudo /usr/bin/X :0 &` on the server and `DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo |grep -i OpenGL`, the OpenGL renderer points towards the NVIDIA GPU, which is what we want:

`OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 418.67`

But `DISPLAY=:0 glxgears` obviously renders `glxgears` on the remote X server named *Display 0*, which is different from the remote X server that gets started when we run `ssh -X` from the Mac (per case 2).

This means that we cannot see the forwarded output, as XQuartz is not connected to Display 0.

**Case 2**

When we create a display through `ssh -X -i ~/.ssh/publickey ubuntu@some.ip` from the Mac, where `some.ip` is the remote machine, and then run `glxinfo | grep -i OpenGL`, the OpenGL renderer points towards the onboard graphics instead:

`OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Pro 560 OpenGL Engine`

We can run `echo $DISPLAY` on the remote and notice that this X server is (usually) called Display 10.

So running `DISPLAY=:10 glxgears`, or simply `glxgears`, does allow us to forward the gears to our Mac-side XQuartz client, but the rendering is slow through the remote machine's onboard graphics.

**Why does the X server choose a different OpenGL renderer in these two cases?** Are they not both configured via `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`?

Is there a way to force XQuartz to connect to a specific display when running `ssh -X`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in XQuartz

$ xhost +
$ ssh -Y username@server

xauth must be installed on the server

Answer (score 0):

you can install virtualGL on both computers.
then use

```
vglrun glxgears
```

to get fast rendering.